Will `cp --update` remove files from destination?
I am using cp -ruv sourcedir/ /mnt/destinationdir to easily maintain a backup of a file tree.
Occasionnally, this command tells me:
remove '/mnt/destinationdir/path/file'

I am surprised, since man cp says:
   --update[=UPDATE]
          control which existing files are updated;
          UPDATE={all,none,none-fail,older(default)}.

   -u     equivalent to --update[=older].  See below


   UPDATE controls which existing files in the destination are
   replaced.  'all' is the default operation when an --update option
   is not specified, and results in all existing files in the
   destination being replaced.  'none' is like the --no-clobber
   option, in that no files in the destination are replaced, and
   skipped files do not induce a failure.  'none-fail' also ensures
   no files are replaced in the destination, but any skipped files
   are diagnosed and induce a failure.  'older' is the default
   operation when --update is specified, and results in files being
   replaced if they're older than the corresponding source file.

When will cp --update=older remove a file at all in the destination dir?
EDIT: The above extract of man cp is for coreutils 9.5, I'm actually with 9.1 which has fewer update controls, but from that man page I don't guess it should behave differently.

Yes, --update keeps the destination in sync with the source, it is not a backup option.
older means that primary flag the process checks to see if an object has changed is the date. If the source object's created/modified date is younger (the destination's is older), the destination object is replaced.
Keeping a destination synced with a source means that objects that have been removed or changed in the source will be removed or changed in the destination. A backup retains objects that have been removed in the source, AND retains previous versions of objects that have been changed in the source.
The purpose of syncing is to keep two (or more) usable copies of the files. It is about redundancy or resiliency more than backup.
